# Android - Toolbar con opacidad y blur

Tags: android, blur

Tengo una app donde tengo una toolbar y quiero hacer que tenga un efecto transparente con un pequeño blur, como puedo lograr esto

Aqui un ejemplo:

http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Expedia-4.1.1.-for-iOS-iPhone-screenshot-001.png

Comment: Lo de blur ni idea de como se podría implementar talvez el autor de esa libreria te pude orientar https://github.com/kassisdion/Android-animated-toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Para obtener un Toolbar transparente:**

En tu Toolbar defines como background el color que pueda ser transparente o blur:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/my_background"        
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

Para el caso transparente, dentro de `/drawable` agrega el archivo fondo `my_background.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Donde `@android:color/transparent` es un color transparente definido por el sistema, por lo tanto tu `Toolbar` sería completamente transparente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Para tener un Toolbar con blur:** podríamos modificar nuestro archivo `/drawable/my_background.xml`  de esta forma :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

y obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Comment: pero y la opacidad?

Comment: define esto en el shape: android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: si, pero eso le daria una opacidad de 0, no? yo lo que quiero es que se alcance a ver lo que hay detras de la toolbar, no se si me doy a entiender

Comment: Si Gus, si defines el color transparente la opacidad es 0 por lo tanto se mostraría lo que esta detras del Toolbar.

Comment: si viste la foto de mi post? ese en un ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr...

Comment: @GustavoSerna los colores en android pueden ser (alpha, red,green,blue) es decir #FF000000 es negro opaco, pero #00000000 es negro transparente

Comment: @GustavoSerna agregue más datos para mostrarte como utilizar el Shape para lo que deseas.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es el efecto de blur del fondo con una imagen. Para ello te recomiendo una librería llamada *[Picasso Transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations)* que complementa a la bien conocida *Picasso*:

```
ImageView fondoBlur;
Picasso.with(fondoBlur.getContext())
          .load(url)
          .transform(new BlurTransformation(getContext(), 25, 1))
          .transform(new ColorFilterTransformation(Color.argb(170, 0, 0, 0)))
          .fit()
          .centerCrop()
          .error(R.drawable.logo)
          .into(fondoBlur);

}
```